# SwiftUI StackNavigationViewStyle issue when rotating iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to implement a Settings view which can be opened taping on a gear icon button in the navigation tool bar.
This button opens a SwiftUI sheet with on Ok button to validate settings and close the settings window.

It works well if you use it without rotating the iPhone.
But if you rotate the phone when the settings window is opened, the Ok button does not work anymore and the window stays on screen (even if you rotate back the phone).

In the console, an error appears when I rotate the phone. Here is the message:

`[Presentation] Attempt to present <…> on <…> (from <…>) which is already presenting`

This issue seems to be linked to `StackNavigationViewStyle()` modifier I use to not have 2 columns on landscape mode.

If I remove the following line, the bug disappears but the layout is no more the one I want.
`.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

Here is a sample code I wrote to reproduce the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // Size class
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var sizeClassV
    
    @State private var showGearView: Bool = false
    
    
    var gearButton: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showGearView.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .accessibility(label: Text("Settings"))
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showGearView, onDismiss: {
            }, content: {
                gearView()
            })
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            //            if sizeClassV == .regular {
            VStack {
                Text("Click on Gear and rotate your iPhone: here is the bug when clicking on Ok: the sheet does not collapse!")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.all)
            }
            .padding(.all)
            .navigationTitle("Bug")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar(content: { gearButton })
        }
        // The bug only happens when adding the StackNavigationViewStyle below
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}



struct gearView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var OKButton: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("OK")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Settings")) {
                        Text("No Settings")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Settings"))
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    OKButton
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```